# Celery cannot connect to RabbitMQ server

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am trying to run celery and it is unable to connect to the RabbitMQ server even though I have correctly set the user, vhost and assigned the appropriate tags

```
celery -A proj worker -l info
```

The above command returns the error

```
[2021-09-28 18:05:37,649: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://test:**@12:5672//: timed out.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)
```

I have initialized the celery app as follows

```
app = Celery('proj',
             broker=f'amqp://test:test@12#4@localhost/test_vhost')
```

---

**I believe this is not working because the password `test@12#4` has the special characters `@` and `#` in it.**

**How do I get this to work without changing the password.**

---

Comment: maybe escape the `@`?

Comment: Try `app = Celery('proj', broker=fr'amqp://test:test@12#4@localhost/test_vhost')` or
`app = Celery('proj', broker=r'amqp://test:test@12#4@localhost/test_vhost')`

Comment: @Superbman Your suggestion did not work

Comment: @C.Nivs Can you provide the escape for ```@```, I am unable to find it. I found it for ```#```, it is ```%23```

Comment: It worked when I replace ```#``` with ```%23```, I guess it was the ```#``` causing the string to terminate and cause a problem and not the ```@```. 

@C.Nivs, it was solved using your suggestion, so if you write an answer Ill mark it as the correct answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be solved using escape sequences.

The issue is not with the `@` character but with the `#`

So if your password is `test@12#4`, you can simply use the escape sequence for the `#` character which is `%23`

The password can be written as `test@12%234`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry there is no way to use such passwords with '@' characters , this is already a known issue with the Celery and the reason is due to urllib3 parse functionality . The only way around is to remove such characters from the password.

For reference please look up the corresponding github issue [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1553)

Comment: I managed to get it work when I used an escape sequence for the ```#``` (%23) character. It turned out ```@``` was not the problem.

I typed the password as ```test@12%234```

Comment: Great .. looks like some updates must have happened in the parsing , since in one of the old issues of stack overflow the escape sequence was suggested but it did not worked.. perhaps you should add an answer for future users...